# Calculate from database

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-field

I have a database with a table called: products.

In this table I have 5 rows:

```
ID as int
Product as varchar
Type as varchar
KG as int
Price_KG as int
```

Now I want to make a dashboard where I can see the total value of a type product.

For example:

[image: Click for preview]

Now I want to see the total value of all type fruits together:
`(5x12)+(8*5)+(38*1)+(30*3)+(50*2)= 328`

So the value what will display is 328.

Same as the type of groente or whatever it will be in the future.

Comment: You should learn [`GROUP BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx/) and aggregate functions. They essentially allow one to summarize data by the selected field values. In your case fruitnames.

Comment: Please show us your work. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Type, SUM(KG * Price_KG) TotalValue
FROM products
GROUP BY Type
;
```

The mysql query above tells the total costs by each type of product.